# Oracle equivalent of T-SQL SET @var = @var + ' ';

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Switching over to Oracle from SQL Server. How do I concatenate a string on to a variable inside a loop? In SQL Server I would've wrote something like

```
DECLARE @var varchar(max);
WHILE ([I'm doing something or whatever on a table])
BEGIN
    SET @var = @var + ' additional text';
END
SELECT @var AS 'result';
```

This is what I have in Oracle so far in my stored procedure. (Going to evolve it to an autogen for ClassMap files for NHibernate)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WWNA.UT_MAPPINGHELPER
(
    TABLE_NAME IN ALL_TABLES.TABLE_NAME%TYPE
    , OWNER_NAME IN ALL_TABLES.OWNER%TYPE
    , CLASS_DEFINITION IN OUT VARCHAR2
)
   IS
   CURSOR TABLE_INFO_CUR
   IS
    SELECT 
        T.TABLE_NAME
        , C.COLUMN_NAME
        ,C.DATA_TYPE
        ,C.DATA_LENGTH
        ,C.DATA_PRECISION
        ,C.NULLABLE
    FROM 
        ALL_TABLES T
        JOIN
        ALL_TAB_COLUMNS C
            ON T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME
                AND T.OWNER = C.OWNER
    WHERE
        T.TABLE_NAME = :TABLE_NAME
        AND T.OWNER = :OWNER_NAME;
    TABLE_INFO_ROW TABLE_INFO_CUR%ROWTYPE;
    build_sql varchar2;
BEGIN
    --VARIABLE build_sql varchar2(4000);
    :build_sql := '';
    OPEN TABLE_INFO_CUR;

    LOOP
        FETCH TABLE_INFO_CUR INTO TABLE_INFO_ROW;
        EXIT WHEN TABLE_INFO_CUR%NOTFOUND;
        SELECT (:build_sql || ' ' || TABLE_INFO_ROW.TABLE_NAME || ' ' || TABLE_INFO_ROW.COLUMN_NAME || ' ' || TABLE_INFO_ROW.DATA_TYPE) INTO :build_sql;
    END LOOP;
    :CLASS_DEFINITION := :build_sql;  

    --DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (CLASS_DEFINITION);


END;
```

Thanks

Comment: WHat's w/all the colons before the variables?  Don't think you need that.  Anyway, you are already using the concat operator, ||, so for variable x, would be "x := x || <stuff>;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with the `build_sql` value within a procedure, leave out the leading colon. That's for a paramterized value, which doesn't apply here.

Also declare the `build_sql` variable's length at the top. This is kind of confusing, because you can leave off the length for parameters, but you need the length do it for a declared variable.

Here's a chopped version of your proc showing the `build_sql` manipulations. Also note that the `CLASS_DEFINITION` parameter variable shouldn't have the colon prefix either:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WWNA.UT_MAPPINGHELPER
(
    TABLE_NAME IN ALL_TABLES.TABLE_NAME%TYPE
    , OWNER_NAME IN ALL_TABLES.OWNER%TYPE
    , CLASS_DEFINITION IN OUT VARCHAR2
)
IS
   ...
   build_sql varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
   build_sql := '';
   ...
   LOOP
      build_sql := build_sql || 'whatever';
   END LOOP;
   CLASS_DEFINITION := build_sql;  
END;
```

Also note that you don't need the `build_sql := ''` line - the variable value will default to blank. Or you can assign an initial value when declaring:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WWNA.UT_MAPPINGHELPER
(
    TABLE_NAME IN ALL_TABLES.TABLE_NAME%TYPE
    , OWNER_NAME IN ALL_TABLES.OWNER%TYPE
    , CLASS_DEFINITION IN OUT VARCHAR2
)
IS
   ...
   build_sql varchar2(4000) := 'start of my sql';
BEGIN
   ...
```

Comment: `build_sql := ''` and `build_sql := NULL` are equivalent.  In Oracle a zero-length string is the same as NULL.  Thus `build_sql := ''; IF build_sql IS NULL THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Yep, it's NULL');` will print `Yep, it's NULL`.

Comment: Excellent point. The concatenation works either way (variable not initialized or variable initialized to `''`) so I decided not to bring up the whole "empty string is null" thing, but you've got me thinking I should have - it's a real gotcha for users moving from SQL Server (or MySQL) to Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WWNA.UT_MAPPINGHELPER
(
    TABLE_NAME IN ALL_TABLES.TABLE_NAME%TYPE
    , OWNER_NAME IN ALL_TABLES.OWNER%TYPE
    , CLASS_DEFINITION IN OUT VARCHAR2
)
   IS
   CURSOR TABLE_INFO_CUR
   IS
    SELECT 
        T.TABLE_NAME
        , C.COLUMN_NAME
        ,C.DATA_TYPE
        ,C.DATA_LENGTH
        ,C.DATA_PRECISION
        ,C.NULLABLE
    FROM 
        ALL_TABLES T
        JOIN
        ALL_TAB_COLUMNS C
            ON T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME
                AND T.OWNER = C.OWNER
    WHERE
        T.TABLE_NAME = :TABLE_NAME
        AND T.OWNER = :OWNER_NAME;

    build_sql varchar2(32767);
BEGIN
    --build_sql := ''; --Not needed, build_sql is already initialised to NULL


    FOR cur_rec IN TABLE_INFO_CUR
    LOOP
        build_sql := build_sql || ' ' || 
                     cur_rec.TABLE_NAME || ' ' || 
                     cur_rec.COLUMN_NAME || ' ' || 
                     cur_rec.DATA_TYPE;
    END LOOP;
    CLASS_DEFINITION := build_sql;  

    --DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (CLASS_DEFINITION);


END;
```

You'd need to define the variable `CLASS_DEFINITION`.

Using a [CURSOR FOR LOOP](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/cursor_for.php) takes care of the opening and closing of the cursor for you as well as batch fetching the results.

You could also use the [CONCAT](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/concat.php) function instead of the [||](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/concat2.php) function.